# Magento 2.1.8 EE unable to update product attribute iin admin

Tags: product-attribute, frontend, admin-panel

I have a product attribute `full_short_description` created from admin panel. For already existing products, I am unable to update the attribute value. But if I create a new product, I can change the value and it is showing the change on frontend too.

For existing products if I change the value it is showing product saved successfully but in admin and frontend showing the old value only. The value is not even updating in database. 
**Reindexing** is done.
**Setup upgrade** and **cache flush** also done.